# IOS: xcodebuild command disable bitcode in Build Settings

Tags: ios, terminal, command, xcodebuild, bitcode

I want to disable Bitcode in the build settings of a .xcodeproj through terminal commands.
I have searched all over but only found commands to build or archive the project from the terminal.
Can you please give me an example how this command looks like?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can list all the keys and values of your project build settings with the command

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings
```

Then find one or more keys you want to override, e.g. ENABLE_BITCODE. These keys can be included as parameters in the build command like so:

```
xcodebuild -target <your target> -configuration <your configuration> ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
```

Comment: As it stands, this is quite a low quality answer. Would you mind explaining further?

Comment: @ham-sandwich Agreed. Updated.